# Failing to connect apache2 with ScriptAlias

Tags: 20.04, apache2, webserver, alias, cgi

I'm trying to set up a `ScriptAlias` on an `apache2` server, but when I try to connect to it using the alias, I get a `Forbidden` error:

[image]

This is my `/etc/apache2/apache.conf`:

[image]

`cgi.load` is enabled on `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/`:

[image]

This is the `/new-cgi/foo.cgi` file and its permissions:

[image]

And if I do `sudo su www-data -s /bin/bash`, I can access the file and execute it without any problems.

There are some warnings (not fatal) in the logs plus a `AH01630: client denied by server configuration` which I believe is the cause of the problem but I can't figure out how to solve it:

[image]

My version of Apache2 is 2.4.41

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scriptalias definition misses a / on the right argument. It really aliasses exactly what you type in the config, so if the left argument has a slash, and the right not, you end up missing a /.

In your case there is no directory or file named `new-cgifoo.cgi` in `/`, so the configuration denies it.

The exact docs are here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias